# How to prevent a user from signing in from more than n computers in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, user-management

I am looking for a way to prevent my web site users, who sign on with a pair of username passwords after their registration, from logging in from multiple computers. Actually i am looking for a way to register the computers that the users log on from and prevent them to give their username,passwords to eachother. I found out that in asp.net and actually in all websites programming languages, it is not possible to detect the mac address of the client's network card. Meanwhile things like browsername and ip address which can be detected via    `httpcontext.current`     are not usable for me because most of the users have dynamic ips. Also i want something more strict than the computer name because it is not something unforefitable.

Please guide me what solutions i can use without involving hardware token based solutions.
Thank you.

Comment: can you use cookie to store some kind of flag?

Comment: Yes. If any solution exists, i d change my user control mechanism to implement it.

Comment: Actually i am looking sth like the mechanism itunes uses for limiting the user to five computers, but in asp.net.

Comment: I want to save client computer's unique identifier on server side and check for the number of computers the user uses in logon process.

Comment: well browser name and its version and ip are the only parameters you can get to identify a session... but you can assign a cookie with a unique GUID and pass it to client browser.. this way user will be identified but if he switch browser on the same machine or clear cookies from browser this information will be lost.

Comment: iTunes is only able to limit to 5 comps because it is a desktop application. Web applications have a _very_ different ecosystem with both more abilities and fewer abilities, depending on the particular application domain.

Comment: Yes and that is why i m looking for a solution that not involves putting sth on client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the best you can do is to record (likely in a database or in-memory cache) when one user is logged in with a timeout and then update the timeout on each request. Then, dissalow that user to log in while the "isLoggedIn" value is current (ie. hasn't expired). You should also expire the timeout on an explicit logout.

In theory, you could also expire the timeout in the sessionExpire event, but we've noticed that event isn't particularly reliable, and we wanted a shorter timeout, hence using our own timeout scenario.

For more stringent securities, you can also stash the session ID, and a browser fingerprint if you feel so inclined, along side the timeout to combat users who get in between your timeout and the session timeout.

In the long run, however, there isn't really any 100% secure way to keep users from sharing accounts. About the best you can do is try to *limit* the "duplicate user" scenario to make it painful for them to have the same account logged on more than once at the same time.

Lastly, just as a side-note, a dynamic IP doesn't typically change that often (unlikely to change within an application session), so you *may* be able to leverage that as well in a fuzzy fashion.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My biggest concern is not concurrent log on but sharing accounts because the website i am developing contains valuable information that users must pay for and i affraid they share accounts because the main audiance is university students and this behaviour is so much common among them.

Comment: There isn't any way to prevent people from sharing their accounts. At least not a reliable one. Any system you try to put in place will simple be worked around if people want to share. You are _much_ better off not worrying about it and instead focus on providing a service / product that is _so good_ and at such a fair price that people will be OK paying for it.